# how to run a timer in a finite loop in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, timer, clock

I have a task where I have to record a video in multiple segments. Let's take the scenario in this way, the user has started recording a video through a webcam and after 5 seconds it has stopped the recording, now we have the value of 5 seconds and our system will start recording the video again for the next 5 seconds and save it in a file. This process will run for multiple times(the value is already set by the user, let's say 3 times).
This is what I want to do in real.

And the Block of code that I shared is an illustration of the real task where code will run a task wait for some time, and repeat the process till it meets a condition which in our case is 3.

This piece of code is working fine but sometimes it skips the counting of seconds. By skipping I mean it will show 1 then lag for 2 seconds then will show 2 and 3 and so on.

I am afraid if I use this technique it might give me the wrong output and I need to be very precise with the recording time.

Is there any way to improve this piece of code?

```
Stopwatch sw;
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sw = new Stopwatch();
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    sw.Start();
}
int counter = 1;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sw.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4))
    {
        sw.Reset();
       
        if (counter < 3)
        {
            sw.Start();
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Reset();
            timer1.Stop();
            counter = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Counter has finished +"counter.ToString());
        }
    }
    lblTime.Text = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", sw.Elapsed);
    
}
```

Comment: there is a timer class in system...threading and system...timers each of them provides the ability to set some delay after the elapsed callback is triggered.

Comment: Show us the code that initializes `timer1`.

Comment: I think you should use `Invoke` method to update a label inside a timer tick event.

Comment: There's no timer in your code. In fact your code seems to be doing the inverse of what you asked. What you ask doesn't seem to need an object-level timer anyway

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? What does `run a block of code` mean? If you run any code in the UI thread, the UI will freeze. That includes any System.Windows.Timer instance. The solution would be to use `Task.Run` or another thread but that would require updating the UI from that background thread. The specifics matter.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the block of code that needs to run for a period of time?

Comment: This is not a very clear question, yet someone voted it up. I suspect people get their friends to vote up their question in the hope someone will find it interesting. It's not working, the only thing that will draw attention is writing a good question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated the Question with more clarity.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've used the drag and drop feature of winform to use the timer. You can see I've enabled it in the button-click event.

Comment: That means you used a System.Windows.Timer timer which runs on the UI thread and responds to [WS_TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer) window messages. The application can't handle any other UI messages while your code runs, not even WS_TIMER messages. The UI will freeze too, because it can't handle the repaint messages sent by the OS. If your timer is set for 4 seconds but your code runs for 15 seconds you'll end up with 2 delayed timer messages waiting for execution when the code finishes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Any suggestion for a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Better than what? I can't guess what the camera API looks like. Is it asynchronous or not? Could you just call `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));` before calling `Stop`? Is the video conversion taking up a lot of time?

Comment: Describe the actual problem and code instead of providing examples that omit important parts. If you want to stop the camera after 5 seconds you can use `await Task.Delay(..);`. If processing the video is too expensive you probably need to do so in another thread. You can use [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-6.0) or TransformBlock to create a separate worker and that will process camera buffers or files one by one in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear and doesn't explain what needs to run. That matters.

One way to repeat a 5-second task 3 times would be to use a CancellationTokenSource that triggers after 5 seconds inside a loop. The worker code would have to check a CancellationToken to see when it needs to terminate :

```
async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
       // The Block
    }
}


async void btnStart_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs args)
{
    var count=3;
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();

        using var cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        await DoWorkAsync(cts.Token);

        lblTime.Text = $("{sw.Elapsed:hh\\:mm\\:ss}");
    }
    MessageBox.Show($"Counter has finished + {count}");
}
```

The UI can be updated after each `await` call, or through a [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-6.0) class. If the code block runs for a long time it can be made to run in the background with [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-run(system-action-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) that can be cancelled using the same `token`. If the block executes asynchronous operations, they could be cancelled as well :

```
async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token,IProgress<string> pg)
{

    try
    {
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
           await Task.Run(()=>{
               //Do Work 1
               pg.Report("Done 1");
               //Do Work 2
               pg.Report("Done 2");
           },token);
        }
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException)
    {
        pg.Report("Time's up!");
    }
}


async void btnStart_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs args)
{
    var pg=new Progress(DisplayProgress);

    var count=3;
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();

        using var cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        await DoWorkAsync(cts.Token,pg);

        lblTime.Text = $("{sw.Elapsed:hh\\:mm\\:ss}");
    }
    MessageBox.Show($"Counter has finished + {count}");
}

void DisplayProgress(string msg)
{
    lblMessage.Text=msg;
}
```

Comment: I guess that should be `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)`.

Comment: Oops, fixed....

Comment: It's also worth noting that CancellationToken works only if the cancelled code cooperates. For example: In the first example, if "The Block"'s execution time exceeds 5 seconds, it will break the loop only after that time, not 5 seconds.

Comment: @Fildor if the actual work blocks, `Task.Run(CancellationToken)` will stop waiting at least. Without any information from the OP it's hard to give a better answer

Comment: I understand that and already +1ed :D Just found that it was worth mentioning. Your point about Task.Run is of course very valid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have updated the question, kindly share your feedback, thank you.